# What does " in the event, doomed" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage

I am struggling to get my head around the following:

> This is probably the best and certainly the most extraordinary graphic
>   novel I have ever come across. Its subject matter, believe it or not,
>   is the search — **in the event, doomed** — for mathematical certainty in
>   the first half of the 20th century.

It's one of a handful of reviews boasted on the back cover of [LOGICOMIX](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Logicomix-An-Epic-Search-Truth/dp/0747597200).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a parenthetical clause modifying "search" in that sentence. What it's saying, in essence, is that the search proved, or is proving, to be unsuccessful.

"In the event" is an adverbial that is tantamount to "in reality" or "actually," or perhaps even "in this case."